# Pyramid importing packages multiple times causing problems

Tags: python-3.x, pyramid

The example below is a pseudo- Pyramid application. It shows functionality in a sub-package.

The issue is both `config.load` and `config.scan` cause the subpackage to be imported. This causes the model objects to be redefined - basically resetting them. This means nothing works when requests are being served.

What's the recommended way to work around this problem?

```
# /__init__.py
def main(global_config, **settings):
   config = Configurator(settings=settings)
   config.include('mypackage')     # This causes mypackage to load and 'RUNNING' to be printed
   ...
   config.scan()                   # This causes mypackage to load again, printing RUNNING and resetting WebSession object

# /mypackage/__init__.py

print('RUNNING')
WebSession = scoped_session(sessionmaker(extension=ZopeTransactionExtension()))       

Base = declarative_base()
class WebPortalUser(Base):
    pass # pseudo-code


def do_dummy():
    s1 = WebSession()
    for i in s1.query(WebPortalUser):
        print(i)

def includeme(config):
    settings = config.registry.settings
    engine = engine_from_config(settings, 'sqlalchemy.')
    WebSession.configure(bind=engine)
    do_dummy()         # This works

@view_config(route_name='test')
def test(request):
    do_dummy()     # Raises sqlalchemy.exc.UnboundExecutionError: Could not locate a bind configured on mapper Mapper|WebPortalUser|webportal_user, SQL expression or this Session
```

Comment: I've also tried not using `config.include` but this means you need to `import mypackage; mypackage.includeme(config)` so there are still two imports happening.

Comment: What happens if you don't initialize the session but call `for i in WebSession.query(WebPortalUser):`?

Answer (score 0):

This problem 'went away by itself', and I haven't been able to create a small, self-contained replicating example.

As a hint to anyone else who may be experiencing similar things, pay very careful attention to the order of the `config.import`, `config.scan` and `config.make_wsgi_app`. These statements should appear in the `main` function in the order I've listed them here.

That's my best guess at the source of the problem.